# Precision in numeric calculations

Tags: pgfmath

When using pgfmathsetmacro with very small of high exponents, it doesn't work. The example below exits by complaining a division by zero. Is there any way to increase the precision that this works or another package which handles this example?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{10e-32}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{10e-30}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{\a/\b}
\c
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{1/\b}
\c
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number range in the default math engine of `pgf` is quite restricted because of the limitations of TeX's numbers. Also the library for fixed point arithmetic does not help with these exponents, because this library only covers ten digits before and after the decimal point.

The example can be processed with the floating point unit library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

\pgfset{fpu}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{10e-32}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{10e-30}

\pgfset{fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{\a/\b}
\c

\pgfset{fpu/output format=sci}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{1/\b}
\c
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 12):

Use a better floating point management framework, the one in `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fpeval{10e-32/10e-30}

\end{document}
```

Note that, differently from `pgf`, the floating point macros are expandable.

Thus, you get the same output from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\varA}{10e-32}
\newcommand{\varB}{10e-30}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{\varA/\varB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Consult `texdoc interface3` for more information about the supported functions and the syntax.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why (in your opinion) this is a better floating point management framework? Better than what?

Comment: @runartrollet Better than `pgfmath`, which was the OP's choice.

Comment: Also better than pgfmath with fpu library?

Comment: @student It lacks random numbers, but full expandability is a plus.

Answer (score 6):

Use `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
\directlua{tex.print(10^(-32)/10^(-30))}

\directlua{tex.print(1/10^(-30))}
\end{document}
```

[image]