# Pgfplots and large exponents in expression and domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, bugs

After I [discovered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315446/4011) the `fpu` library for increased precision, I tried to make a plot involving large exponents. I choosed as an example a plot of the gravitational force of the moon on a test mass in SI-units.

How can I make the following code to handle the large exponents and get a reasonable plot automatically.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      %% Plot Gravitational force of the moon
      \td{\mM}{7.36e22} % mass of the moon in kg
      \td{\rM}{1.74e6} % radius of the moon in m
      \td{\mK}{1}% test mass in kg
      \td{\gG}{6.67e-11} % gravitational constant
      \addplot[domain=0:10e6] gnuplot {\gG*\mK*\mM/(\rM + x)^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously one could choose more reasonable units for the example above, but my point is how `pgfplots` (with or without `gnuplot`) can handle plots with such high exponents directly.

Comment: Hmm. Strange and puzzled. `gnuplot` by itself is perfectly fine with the numbers.

Comment: The error is ... puzzling too: `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   e
` at the `\begin{axis}`. And yes, I have added `compat` settings.

Comment: Probably related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal --- @christian-feuersänger ?

Comment: Who you use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to simply set values?  Why don't you do `\def\mM{7.36e22}` instead of `\td{\mM}{7.36e22}`?  Also, in conjunction with FPU, `7.36e22` is not a valid floating point format.

Comment: Same problem when using `\def`. I didn't have any specific reason to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` I just thought that this is the standard way to define numbers for pgf.

Comment: @student Sorry for the confusion.  I meant `\def` *without* FPU.  The problem is  in the `pgfplots` axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pgfplots` axes cannot handle FPU formatted values.  You have to move the FPU instructions inside the `axis` environment and scope them.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    %% Plot Gravitational force of the moon
    {
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
      \td{\mM}{7.36e22} % mass of the moon in kg
      \td{\rM}{1.74e6} % radius of the moon in m
      \td{\mK}{1}% test mass in kg
      \td{\gG}{6.67e-11} % gravitational constant
      \addplot[domain=0:10e6] gnuplot {\gG*\mK*\mM/(\rM + x)^2};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

To simply set values to a macro, you don't need to invoke the math parser (this should also speed up typesetting a little).  Gnuplot can handle large exponents, so there is not need to digest them through PGF first.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    %% Plot Gravitational force of the moon
    \def\mM{7.36e22} % mass of the moon in kg
    \def\rM{1.74e6} % radius of the moon in m
    \def\mK{1}% test mass in kg
    \def\gG{6.67e-11} % gravitational constant
    \addplot[domain=0:10e6] gnuplot {\gG*\mK*\mM/(\rM + x)^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. However I don't really understand, what it means here, that the axis environment cannot handle FPU formatted values. Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Comment: @student Internally an FPU float looks like `1Y2.17765411e23]`.  It is quite obvious why this cannot be parsed properly.  I don't know if this is documented.

Comment: I don't really understand it. Here is what I think: Suppose I define something like `\pgfsetmacro{\V}{1.72e15}` this is stored internally like `1Y1.72e15]`. Then if I do something like `\addplot gnuplot {x*\V*}` the `x` is **not** stored in the FPU format, because the axis environment doesn't support it, but `\V` is and not proper formatted value can passed to gnuplot. But if this view is correct, I don't see why it helps to move the pgfkeys setting inside of the axis environment.

Comment: @student `\addplot` is perfectly aware of the FPU (this is documented), but things like the axis ticks and labels are not FPU-ready.  That's why it helps to “hide” the FPU from the `axis` environment by grouping.